# Add a do_action to post_content of wp_insert_post

Tags: plugins

I created a plugin that is supposed to create a page with a contact form..

I got it to the point where it creates a page on activation of plugin, but I don't know how to give the post_content a do_action..
Here is my create page function

```
function ap_post_creation() {
    global $wpdb;
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();

    //$content = do_action('show-ap-form');

    $args = array(
        'post_author' => $user_id,
        'post_content' => 'Hallo',
        'post_title' => 'Contact',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post_type' => 'page',
        'comment_status' => 'closed',
    );

    wp_insert_post($args);
}
```

And here is my add_action function

```
<?php  
add_action('show-ap-form', 'show_ap_form');

function show_ap_form() {
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    }
?>
    <form method="post">
        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter your name">
        <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Enter your e-mail">
        <textarea name="message" placeholder="Enter your message"> </textarea>
    </form>
<?php
}
?>
```

How can I attach the contact form to the newly created Contact page?

Comment: did you mean you need contact form attached in new created page after plugin activation?

Comment: Yes, I need the contact form to be attached to the newly created page.

Comment: I see, how about $_POST['submit'], where is come from?

Comment: I was thinking to put the code there for inserting the info in the database. The form refreshes the page and goes into the if statement. But the form is not yet 100%.

Comment: I prefer create shortcode for form, then add shortcode as value of 'post_content'

Comment: Hmm, that looks interesting! I didn't know something like that existed.. That does make things easier! But how can I add the form to the bottom of the page (Like have a user pick a page and then add the form to the bottom of that specific page)

Comment: I just answer as your question, I hope you get insight about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*@Peter van der Net*, here my approach, I create [shortcode](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) for newly created page. So we don't have to save element form into database, and it make easy by user if they need move form to another page by shortcode. For submission, I use hook `wp` and handle data of form submission. For your issue, this is my simple code that you can figure it out.

```
function ap_post_creation() {
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    $args = array(
        'post_author'    => $user_id,
        'post_content'   => '[foobar]', //shortcode tag
        'post_title'     => 'Contact',
        'post_status'    => 'publish',
        'post_type'      => 'page',
        'comment_status' => 'closed',
    );
    wp_insert_post($args);
}

add_action( 'wp', 'show_ap_form' );
function show_ap_form( $wp ) {
    if ( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) ) {
        //run your stuff here don't forget to sanitize
    }
}

add_shortcode( 'foobar', 'ap_shortcode_form' );
function ap_shortcode_form( $atts ) {
    ob_start();
?>
    <form method="post">
        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter your name">
        <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Enter your e-mail">
        <textarea name="message" placeholder="Enter your message"> </textarea>
        <button name="submit"><?php _e( 'Submit' ) ?></button>
    </form>
<?php
    $html_form = ob_get_clean();
    return $html_form;
}
```

Comment: Not quite sure what to do with the wp hook yet, but that is something for me to research :) thanks a lot!

Comment: if you do `echo '<pre>';
print_r($wp);
echo '</pre>';` inside that function, just say if need conditional statement about those given data with our current page that contain form. Yes just research, good luck with your project. :)

Comment: If I fill in the form the only data I can find back in the array is the name(in query_vars), how can I get the content of email and message?

Comment: Of course you really need to validate your form, validate every input name.Then save all value into database as your need.

Comment: If you know [`wp_mail`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_mail/) you can use it for your contact form. Just research on this site. There will be more advance then.

Comment: Would a `template` work better here than a `shortcode` as the content? A `template` is just as easily set, and it conforms to WordPress best practice in this situation.

Comment: @ Nathan Powell, yes maybe, but in plugin I won't ask my user to create template for theme they use.